# Overlay image on top of the UI taking the photos

Tags: iphone, camera, overlay, uiimagepickercontroller

im making an iphone app that is somewhat similar to fatbooth... Im trying to recreate the overlay image effect they have when you have to put your head in that certain area on the photo. Anyone know how?
Thanks

Comment: facing same problem...
can anyone help ???

Answer (score 3):

Place your custom overlay view in the `cameraOverlayView` property of the UIImagePickerController.